# Uncaught TypeError when adding links with role=button" on page, which interferes with after pseudo element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-awesome, pseudo-element

When I add a link that opens a new webpage or downloads a file a font awesome icon (external link and download icons, respectively) is added automatically using a combination of JQuery and CSS using the `::after` pseudo-element Also a tooltip is shown on link hover telling the user that the link either opens a new webpage or downloads a file.

This works perfectly. However, when I add a link with role="button", like `<a type="button" href="https://twitter.com/" class="btn-floating"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>` on the same page it results that the Font Awesome icons are not added and the tooltips also do not show anymore on link hover.

When I remove the link with role="button" the other links render as expected again.

After inspecting the page I was presented with the following error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined

[image: Inspect Page Screenshot of Uncaught TypeError]

More specifically, the following line in the script was highlighted: return `$(this).attr("href").match(/\.(pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|xls|xlxs|epub|odt|odp|ods|txt|rtf)$/i);`

However, when I add the relevant code in the code snippet, everything works just fine (until now)!

I have reached a dead end. Who can shine his or her light on this problem?

Kind regards,

```js
/** Icons JavaScript **/
/** Add new-window and download classes automatically to links **/
$('a[target=_blank]').addClass('new-window');
$("a").filter(function () {
   return $(this).attr("href").match(/\.(pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|xls|xlxs|epub|odt|odp|ods|txt|rtf)$/i);
}).addClass('download');

/** Links JavaScript **/
/* Check for links in document */
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
/* Create index for download links unique id*/
var downloadIndex = 0;
/* Create index for new window links unique id*/
var newWindowIndex = 0;
/* Check links on page */
for (var linkIndex = 0; linkIndex < links.length; linkIndex++) {
   /* Creating a span to wrap the screen-reader text */
   var srTxtWrapper = document.createElement("span");
   /* Add class .sr-only to screen-reader span */
   srTxtWrapper.classList.add("sr-only");

   if (links[linkIndex].classList.contains("download")) {
      /* Add download attribute */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("download", "");
      /* Add unique id to download link */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("id", "download-file-" + downloadIndex);
      /* Add title attribute saying download file */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("title", "download bestand");
      /* Add data-toggle tooltip data attribute */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("data-toggle", "tooltip");
      /* Creating the screen-reader text */
      var srTxt = document.createTextNode("(deze link downloadt een bestand)");
      /* Adding the screen-reader text to the span*/
      srTxtWrapper.appendChild(srTxt);
      links[linkIndex].appendChild(srTxtWrapper);
      /* Increase downloadIndex by one for next download link */
      downloadIndex++;
   }
   else if (links[linkIndex].classList.contains("new-window")) {
      /* Add target _blank attribute for link to open in new window */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
      /* Add unique id to new window link */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("id", "new-window" + newWindowIndex);
      /* Add title attribute saying link opens in new window */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("title", "open in nieuw venster/tab");
      /* Add data-toggle tooltip data attribute */
      links[linkIndex].setAttribute("data-toggle", "tooltip");
      /* Creating the screen-reader text */
      var srTxt = document.createTextNode("(deze link opent in een nieuw venster/tab)");
      /* Adding the screen-reader text to the span*/
      srTxtWrapper.appendChild(srTxt);
      links[linkIndex].appendChild(srTxtWrapper);
      /* Increase newWindowIndex by one for next newWindow link */
      newWindowIndex++;
   }
}
```

```css
/* Font Awesome icons for new-window and download classes links (not in button links) */
a.new-window:not(.button)::after,
a.download:not(.button)::after {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-left: 0.35rem
}

a.new-window:not(.button)::after {
  content: "\f08e"
}

a.download:not(.button)::after {
  content: "\f019"
}

/* button floating */
.btn-floating {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px
}

.btn-floating i {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 47px
}

.btn-floating i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: inherit;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center
}

.btn-floating:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}

.btn-floating:before {
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link href=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.usebootstrap.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
 <p>Link that opens a webpage in new window/tab: <a href="https://www.d2l.com/" target="_blank" class="new-window"
                  rel="noreferrer noopener">D2L
                  Homepage</a></p>
                  
                  <hr>
                   <p>Link that opens as PDF download: <a
                  href="https://www.d2l.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Video-transcript.pdf" download target="_blank" class="download"
                  rel="noreferrer noopener">Transcript of Inclusive Learning with D2L Brightspace (PDF)</a></p>
                  
                  <hr>
                   <a type="button" href="https://twitter.com/" class="btn-floating"><i class="fab fa-twitter" style="color: blue"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50626843/19299088

I replaced ".attr()" with ".prop()" it fixed the issue. Everything works as expected and I don't get the error "TypeError: $(…).attr(…)" anymore.